# Can we do Json Serialization with net tcp binding in wcf?

Tags: .net, wcf, json, serialization, binding

Can we do Json Serialization with net tcp binding in wcf? If yes, whats the configuration required? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? JSON is only useful when you call your service from Javascript, and that means HTTP...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - JSON is very useful for performance and also when SOAP is far too verbose

Comment: @Maslow, you're right, and I actually changed my opinion about this since I posted this comment...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to find the serialize behavior and replace it, [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/29/wcf-extensibility-icontractbehavior.aspx) can help you.